# Cypress doesn't connect to firestore emulator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, cypress

I have configured firestore emulator which seems to work since I have different data on localhost and when website is actually on server. While trying to write cypress test I encountered problem that cypress doesn't connect to emulator and doesn't have data of any databases (emulator/realtime). How can it be fixed?

**firebase config**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
//configuration
});
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

if (window.location.hostname === "localhost") {
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, "localhost", 8080);
}

export default db;
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? if so, can you share error by updating your question?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you should enable `experimentalForceLongPolling`

In your case, you should replace:

```
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
```

with

```
// NOTE: do NOT put this in production.
const db = initializeFirestore(firebaseApp, { experimentalForceLongPolling: true });
```

in a namespaced implementation, it can be set like this:

```
// NOTE: do NOT put this in production.
firebase.firestore().settings({ experimentalForceLongPolling: true })
```